# CocoaSoundCloudAPI crashes when I connect to company FaceBook account. Fix required

Tags: soundcloud

(I've previously tried SoundCloud GoogleGroups (defunct?), and directly to my SoundCloud contact for this.  Told to post the issue here.)

Just trying to get to grips with SoundCloudAPI on iOS and I found a nasty error.  Either this is a bug in the API, or a bug in SoundCloud, or (most likely) I'm doing something wrong.  :)    But the end result would be a broken app, so I'm keen to understand what is going wrong here.

I set up a new iOS project, following the Tobias video, and the CocoaSoundCloudAPI readme.

Using theSCShareViewController I connect to a test SoundCloud account I made for my company.  I then create a new connection within the app to a test company FaceBook account.  I click install, and Allow All permissions.

The app then hangs, with  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'
on the line (in SCRecordingSaveViewController.m) :

```
cell.textLabel.text = [connection objectForKey:@"display_name"];
```

Whenever I run the app now, it crashes on this line.

When I dump out the contents of the connection NSDictionary, it looks like there are two connections listed in self.availableConnections, a "facebook_page" connection with the display_name I gave for my company FaceBook page.  But also a second "facebook_profile" with a null display_name.  It's this second connection that is causing the API to crash.  Presumably the API developers were never expecting a null display_name, but also I don't understand why it's listing two FaceBook connections at all.

If I investigate the value of "display_name" further then Xcode tells me "Variable is not a CFString" and indeed if I look at the class then it is not.

Going into SoundCloud in a browser, I can list the connections, and it shows two of them.  One with the name of my company FB account, and a second one:

"http://facebook.com/profile.php?id=************* is your primary Facebook user account"

If I disconnect both of these I can use the SoundCloudAPI again without it crashing.

I then created new personal test SoundCloud and FaceBook accounts, and did the same thing again within the app.  This time it did not crash (and in fact worked great), and the connection NSDictionary has one connection "facebook_profile" with a valid display_name.  SoundCloud via a browser also lists just one connection.

Note that this also happens with CocoaSoundCloudDemo with no code changes.

I can also hack around with the code to avoid crashing when connecting to my company account:-

```
// cell.textLabel.text = [connection objectForKey:@"display_name"]; 

id displayName = [connection objectForKey:@"display_name"];
if ([displayName isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) 
{
    cell.textLabel.text = (NSString*)displayName;
}
```

...which gives me two rows with FB connections, but the second is blank.  With some effort I can work out what they are doing here in the code, and not show a row if the display_name is invalid, but obviously I'd rather not have to do that and use the standard API code.

SO, long story short:-

1) Does SoundCloud allow you to connect to a company FaceBook account?   Is there some special setup you need to do on that FaceBook account so that SoundCloud only sees the "Facebook_profile" and not also "Facebook_page"?   The problem seems to be within SoundCloud itself, and not the iOS API, but it is the API that crashes.

2) From my test app, if a user tries to connect a SoundCloud account to a company FaceBook account (at least, with the minimal setup that I have in mine), then the SoundCloudAPI will crash with an exception, and my entire app will continue to crash until the user logs on with a browser to SoundCloud and removes the two connections manually.   Surely this can't be good, but I've Googled for anyone with a similar issue and found nothing.  Without finding a fix for this I can't use the full API in my app for fear my users will hit the same crash bug, and perhaps will have to create a cut-down custom UI that avoids the need to share to FaceBook etc.

Comment: Hi, this is Tobias from the SoundCloud iOS Team. What you are trying to do (as far as I understand your description), should work. We will have a look into this, but this may take a few days.

Comment: No problem, I'm in no rush with this.  I can provide some more info, such as screenshots of the SoundCloud site with the two FB connections, or the data returned in the connection list in the API, if you need it.  You should be able to reproduce the error by creating a new FB account, choosing a company one instead of a personal one, and then using the CocoaSoundCloudDemo to connect to FB.  That's all I did.

Comment: Just wondered if you'd made any progress on this one?   Even if that progress is just that you can't repeat the issue.  I can't add SoundCloud support to my app until I know it's not going to cause my users problems.

Comment: Hi @MarkTerry, If displayName is no NSString, what exactly is it? :) This would help us reproduce the bug. Is it possible that it's a NSNull?

Comment: The first displayname is __NSCFString and is the same string as my FaceBook account.  The "type" and "service" for this is coming up as "facebook_page".

The second displayName (that causes the crash) is NSNull.
The "type" and "service" for this is coming up as "facebook_profile".

Comment: Any progress on this one?  I'd really like to add SoundCloud support into my app, but right now I have a FaceBook account that seems to completely crash the API you are providing (and would thus crash my app completely every time until the user bothered to visit the SoundCloud website).  Ultimately I guess I'll have to get around to debugging your API and adding some proper error-handling.  But I'd _much_ rather be using the official codebase so that when you change stuff I can just copy the new code over without having to hack it again.

Comment: Another month gone and no response.  Am I to assume that the SoundCloud team are no longer looking into this bug?

Comment: As a followup to this, if anyone is following the same path, I gave up waiting (3.5 months) for the SoundCloud API team to reply.  Instead I've hacked out of CocoaSoundCloudAPI all the Connection (link to FaceBook etc) interface code.  Even with a personal FB account it just didn't work for me - although it didn't crash out like the company FB account did.  I figure my users can upload to SoundCloud and then go on the website to publish to FB if they want.  Life is too short for me to be giving tech support to my users on why SoundCloud API is not working for them.  :)

Answer (score 1):

sorry that we have not come back to you earlier. 
It is always good to receive feedback from our SDK users and yes we should check
against `nil` values and handle this case accordingly.

However, I investigated the situation you are describing and actually it worked
flawlessly for me. Two rows for Facebook were displayed properly as soon as I
connected my SoundCloud account w/ the new Facebook page in my SoundCloud profile settings.

You can also check which accounts are connected by running

```
curl "https://api.soundcloud.com/me/connections.json?oauth_token=<YOUR_OAUTH_TOKEN>
```

In my case I received something like this

```
{
"kind": "connection",
"id": 12345678,
"created_at": "2013/01/10 15:55:20 +0000",
"display_name": "Testpage",
"post_publish": true,
"post_favorite": true,
"type": "facebook_page",
"service": "facebook_page",
"uri": "https://api.soundcloud.com/connections/12345678"
},
{
"kind": "connection",
"id": 12345679,
"created_at": "2013/01/10 11:07:56 +0000",
"display_name": "Rob",
"post_publish": true,
"post_favorite": true,
"type": "facebook_profile",
"service": "facebook_profile",
"uri": "https://api.soundcloud.com/connections/12345679"
}
```

So while uploading a new sound via the SDK, I got two Facebook rows in
the sharing section. Are you still experiencing this issue?

We will release an update to our iOS SDK soon, so stay tuned and thanks for your feedback.